# How to combine a ListContourPlot and ListPlot3D from array data

Tags: plotting

Can 2D ListContourPlot and 3D ListPlot3D  be combined so that the 2D plot is the bottom surface of the 3D plot? I am not able to join it using Show.

I have a 2d plane drawn by ListContourPlot and I have its 3D image drawn by ListPlot3D, by importing a large data in table format. How can I combine these two?

Comment: If none of the solutions in the linked thread suit your needs, please edit your question to explain why, and we can reopen this.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is similar to that, but I need to plot the array data for which I am using ListPlot3D in place of Plot3D and ListContourPlot in place of ContourPlot.
I have followed the same code but unable to combine the graphics, may be because some functions differ for List.

Comment: Then, can you edit your question to include the code you tried that did not work?